# Where is libYAJLIPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, static-libraries, yajl

Where can i get the libYAJLIPhone-0.2.2 for my iphone project?
I can only find the source code and old version links that don't work

The links below all give the error further below:

[1](https://rel.me.s3.amazonaws.com/yajl/libYAJLIPhone-0.2.2.zip) [2](https://rel.me.s3.amazonaws.com/yajl/libYAJLIPhone-0.2.6.zip)

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

The GIT [site](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc) Says to copy the Copy `YAJLiOS.framework` to your project directory. But i cant find this file on the master branch...

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest file can be found in [Here](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc/downloads)